# How to express the full range of values of a char in F#?

Tags: unicode, f#

Unicode code points range from `U+000000` to `U+10FFFF`. While writing myself a lexer generator in F#, I ran into the following problem:

For the character set definitions, I intend to use a simple tuple of type `char * char`, expressing a range of characters. Omitting some peripheral details, I also need a range I call `All`and which is supposed to be the full unicode range.

Now, it is possible to define a char literal as such: `let c = '\u3000'`. And for strings, it is also possible to refer to a real 32 bit code point like this: `let s = "\U0010FFFF"`. But the latter does not work for chars. The reason being, that a char in .NET is a 16 bit unicode character and the code point would yield 2 words, not one.

So the question is - is there a way I can stick to my `char * char` tuple and get my `All` defined somehow or do I need to change it to `uint32 * uint32` and define all my character ranges as 32 bit values? And if I have to change, is there a type I should prefer over `uint32` I did not discover yet?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: I assume you are trying to use UTF-8 - from wikipedia: UTF-8 encodes ... valid code points in the Unicode code space ... using one to four 8-bit bytes

Comment: Nope - I hoped to get away with the F# type `char` which is basically a 16 bit unicode character. (.NET default encoding: Unicode, which I think is the same as UTF-16).

Comment: I think this should be OK

Comment: Think I know now what to do best: ``Char.ConvertToUtf32()`` represents an utf-32 as a ``int32``. So I will use that type and change to code points entirely.

Comment: You might want to exclude the surrogate pair "codepoint" range 0xD800 to 0xDFFF. (They are numerically identical to UTF-16 code unit values from encoding codepoints that require two code units.)